# Get the name of the id that matches the category id list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame like the one below, I want to extract a name that matches the list of ids.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
    'name': ['person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane', 'vase', 'scissors', 'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']
})
```

For example, given `category_id_list = [4, 1, 1, 2]`, the expected output is:

```py
['motorcycle', 'person', 'person', 'bicycle']
```

I tried my best to find the same question, but I couldn't find it. I need an `.isin()` that is not sorted, including duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like?

```
>>> df.set_index('id').loc[[4, 1, 1, 2], 'name'].tolist()
['motorcycle', 'person', 'person', 'bicycle']
>>>
```

You could set the `id` column as the index and then `loc` the rows.

Without `set_index`:

```
>>> df.loc[[df['id'].eq(i).idxmax() for i in [4, 1, 1, 2]], 'name'].tolist()
['motorcycle', 'person', 'person', 'bicycle']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also came up with it, is it difficult without using `.set_index()`?

Comment: @Keiku Edited my answer without `set_index` :)

Answer (score 1):

We can try `merge`

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': category_id_list}).merge(df)
```

---

```
   id        name
0   4  motorcycle
1   1      person
2   1      person
3   2     bicycle
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using a regular for loop

my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
    'name': ['person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane', 'vase', 'scissors', 'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']
})

def output(category,name):
    output=[]
    for i in category:
        output.append(name[i-1])
    return output  

category=[4,1,1,2]
print(output(category,df['name']))
```

output

```
['motorcycle', 'person', 'person', 'bicycle']
```